# How to find out if a polytope contains a sphere?

Tags: convex-polytopes, linear-programming

Given a polytope described by linear inequalities $Ax \le b, x \in \mathbb R^n$, how do you find out if there exist a (non degenerate) sphere of dimension $n-1$ contained in the polytope?

Thanks!

Comment: If the polytope is nonempty, there there is a sphere inside, albeit maybe a small one. Perhaps I misunderstand the question? If not, then it reduces to determining emptiness, or feasibility.

Comment: Take the non empty polytope (it is in fact a line) : $\{ (x, y), x \le 0, -x \le 0\}$. It doesn't contain a non degenerate circle. (I added the fact that the sphere must be non degenerate to the question)

Comment: OK, I stand corrected. I should have said "If the polytope has a nonempty *interior*..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the polytope is less than full dimensional, it is contained in one of the hyperplanes $a_i \cdot x = b_i$, where $a_i$ is a row of $A$ and $b_i$ the corresponding entry of $b$.  You can tell whether this is the case (for 
a particular $i$) by linear programming: minimize $a_i \cdot x$ subject to 
$Ax \le b$.  The polytope is contained in the hyperplane iff the optimal objective value is $b_i$.